# NVIDIA CUFFT limit on sizes and batches for FFT with scikits.cuda

Tags: cuda, fft, scikits

This question will use scikits.cuda [1] in the Python command line, but may equivalently be attempted in pure C/CUDA (which I haven't tried).

I'm attempting to create a CUFFT plan for 1D complex-to-complex transforms that'll be applied to many inputs (so lots of batches). With a Tesla C2050, I do the following

```
import scikits.cuda.fft as cufft
import numpy as np
p = cufft.Plan((64*1024,), np.complex64, np.complex64, batch=100)
p = cufft.Plan((64*1024,), np.complex64, np.complex64, batch=1000)
p = cufft.Plan((64*1024,), np.complex64, np.complex64, batch=10000) # !!!
```

The last attempted plan raises a cufftAllocFailed exception. If I reduce the size of the transform (from 64K), I can get a batch of 10'000, but currently I need 64K-sized transforms.

My question is: is this a hard limit in CUFFT? And if so, where in the CUDA [2] or CUFFT [3] documentation are limits on transform size versus batch (versus dimension?) specified?

[1] http://scikits.appspot.com/cuda

[2] http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/CUDA_C_Programming_Guide.pdf

[3] http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/pdf/CUDA_CUFFT_Users_Guide.pdf

Comment: As far as I am aware (I don't use CUFFT) the memory usage of CUFFT is determined by a complex relationship between FFT size, batch size, FFT-type, and algorithm. In other words, it cannot be easily predicted. I understand that in your application the size of the transform is given, but shouldn't you be able to freely choose the batch size? I assume that past a certain batch size there is no noticeable performance increase, so why not run some experiments and chose the smallest batch size that gives "full" performance. You could also consider using a GPU with 6 GB of memory, such as a C2075.

Comment: I *think* it is related to the fact that only 2^27 elements can be bound to a linear texture, which is also the largest CUFFT size advertised (NVIDIA: "1D transform sizes up to 128 million elements"). Plan creation appears to succeed as long as 64K * batch is less than 2^27. Doesn't appear to be related to amount of memory on board.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a hard limit of roughly 2^27 elements in a plan.